# Minimum and Maxiumum of like values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to take a range of values in a number of sets, and write a VBA code to fill in grouped cells with the minimum and maximum values in the range.

Example Table

| Group | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 10 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 5 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 3 |

The expected outputs should be a table or cells that say

```
A Range : 3-10
B Range : 1-3
```

Obviously, I could do this with a min and max formula, for each set, however, I'm wondering if there's a way to do this in VBA as the number of sets is in excess of a few hundred

Comment: You can use `MINIFS()` and `MAXIFS()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly do this with VBA and/or Power Query, although, as others have written and you are aware, formulas are a viable option.

**Source Data**
[image]

for VBA:

- Read the source data into a VBA array for fastest processing
- create a class module to hold the minumum and maximum values
- Group the ranges using a Dictionary, which in turn holds the class object
- Create a results array and write it to the worksheet.

**Class Module**

```
'ReNAME this "cGroup"
Option Explicit
Private pMin As Long
Private pMax As Long

Public Property Get Min() As Long
    Min = pMin
End Property
Public Property Let Min(Value As Long)
    pMin = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Max() As Long
    Max = pMax
End Property
Public Property Let Max(Value As Long)
    pMax = Value
End Property
```

**Regular Module**

```
'Set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Option Explicit
Sub generateRanges()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant, v As Variant
    Dim I As Long
    Dim D As Dictionary, sKey As String
    Dim cG As cGroup
    
'set the source and results worksheets
Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
Set wsRes = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1)

'read source data into vba array
With wsSrc
    vSrc = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
End With

'set dictionary to collect the data
Set D = New Dictionary
    D.CompareMode = TextCompare

'iterate through the data
'pull out the min and max of the range
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    sKey = vSrc(I, 1)
    Set cG = New cGroup
    If Not D.Exists(sKey) Then
        cG.Max = vSrc(I, 2)
        cG.Min = vSrc(I, 2)
        D.Add Key:=sKey, Item:=cG
    Else
        With D(sKey)
            .Max = IIf(.Max > vSrc(I, 2), .Max, vSrc(I, 2))
            .Min = IIf(.Min < vSrc(I, 2), .Min, vSrc(I, 2))
        End With
    End If
Next I

'create the results array
ReDim vRes(0 To D.Count, 1 To 2)

'Column Headers
vRes(0, 1) = "Range"
vRes(0, 2) = "Value"

I = 0
For Each v In D.Keys
    I = I + 1
    vRes(I, 1) = v & " Range"
    vRes(I, 2) = D(v).Min & "-" & D(v).Max
Next v

'write results to results worksheet

With rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .Value = vRes
    .Style = "Output" 'not internationally aware
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Or, using Power Query *(which I prefer because its shorter and easier to program)* available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365:

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

**M Code**

```
let

//Read in the table
// Change Table name in next line to actual table name
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

//type the data
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Group", type text}, {"Value", Int64.Type}}),

//Group by "Group"
//   then generate the min-max string
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Group"}, {{"Value", 
        each Text.From(List.Min([Value])) & "-" & Text.From(List.Max([Value])), Text.Type }
        }),

//Add the word " Range" to the Group
    addRange = Table.TransformColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Group", each _ & " Range", Text.Type})

in
    addRange
```

Either produces the same results from your data:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, VBA isn't the best solution in this case because a single formula can extract all the data you want. There is no need to make a different formula for each group.

```
=MINIFS(INDEX(Data,,2),INDEX(Data,,1),H2) & " - " & MAXIFS(INDEX(Data,,2),INDEX(Data,,1),H2)
```

[image]

The formula for the dynamic named range is `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1,2)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with formula then could try below formula with `Excel365`.

```
D2=UNIQUE(A2:A6)
E2=MINIFS(B2:B6,A2:A6,D2#)&"-"&MAXIFS(B2:B6,A2:A6,D2#)
```

[image]